# NetSuite - OnValidateLine not working

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

My validate line function below appears to only work on the second time of clicking add. So if the amount is 500 and I set the discount to 100, on hitting the add button it should be 400. It doesn't work. If I click the line again, the it seems the discount applies twice - amount becomes 300. How do I resolve this?

```js
function OnValidateLine(type, name) {
  var count = nlapiGetLineItemCount('expense')
  var total = nlapiGetFieldValue('usertotal')

  for (var x = 1; x <= count; x++) {
    var amount = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('expense', 'amount');
    var discount = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('expense', 'custcolptc_discount');
    if (discount) {
      nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('expense', 'amount', amount - discount)
    }
    return true;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to use NetSuite's typical discount items instead of coding for this? Are they not applicable on Expense lines?

There doesn't appear to be any actual validation happening here, so have you considered moving this to `fieldChanged` instead? You could trigger the update any time the *Amount* or *Discount* field changes, though it seems like there will be many more scenarios and use cases you'll have to handle with this logic.

Comment: NetSuite doesn't have discount feature for vendor bills like it does for invoices hence why I've had to code this. I need to apply discount at the line level. Some of our vendors offer us discounts so we need a way to reducing this from the bill. My code works but only from the 2nd line on wards. OK - I will try the fieldChanged.

Comment: Just noticed that you're never actually reading `x` or `count`. You shouldn't need the `for` loop at all as you're only modifying a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually doing anything with your loop.

Also the way you are going about this is fraught with issues.

You should probably do this in the recalc event rather than a line validation event.

If I were doing this I'd tend manage a 'synthetic' expense line that is the total of calculated discounts. The way you are currently doing this if someone changes the expense description you'll end up with the discount applied twice. If you use a discount line then you'll just total up the discounts and add or update the discount line.

Typically for a Client script you would need to advance the pointer for each line you are looking at. In the untested example below the 'id field?' would be memo or account columns (you'll have to set the account anyway):

```
var totalDiscount = 0;
var discountExpenseAt = 0;
for(var i = nlapiGetLineItemCount('expense'); i> 0; i--){
   if(nlapiGetLineItemValue('expense', 'id field?', i) == 'discount identifier') {
discountExpenseAt = i;
continue;
}
   totalDiscount += parseFloat(nlapiGetLineItemValue('expense', 'custcolptc_discount', i)) ||0;
}
if(totalDiscount) {
if(discountExpenseAt){
nlapiSelectCurrentLineItem('expense', discountExpenseAt);
nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('expense', 'amount', totalDiscount.toFixed(2));
nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('expense', 'id field?', 'discount identifier');
nlapiCommitCurrentLineItem('expense');
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I've updated my code and removed the loop which I didn't realise was doing nothing! I think I have what I need now - thanks for the code snippet.